# Loop não esta listando imagens como esperado

Tags: php, javascript

Estou me aventurando e tentando criar uma galeria de imagens, e para isso peguei uma galeria já criada, e estou tentando adapta-la para funcionar com LOOP do PHP.

Eu tenho 08 imagens (Números de 1 à 8) já cadastradas no BD, criei o PHP para que dar o loop nessas imagens, limitando a quantidade para 6 imagens por lopp, para elas se enquadre no estilo, ou seja cada loop traz somente 06 imagens por vez.

Para trazer as duas imagens restante, eu clico para avançar, mas o que acontece é que me traz uma nova relação porem sem as imagens restantes.

E reparei que quando retiro essa DIV abaixo:

```
<div class="photos-slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 932px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
   <span class="filler"></span>
</div>
```

que esta abaixo do LOOP, ele desaparece, porem se demos um INSPECIONAR veremos que ele esta, porém não visível.

Estou postando o código usad, e endereço para verificação do que esta acontecendo abaixo:

```
    <?php
include "conexao.php";

$fundo_show_room_cor = $_POST['fundo_show_room_cor'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM showroom");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>

<style>
/* SHOW-ROOM */
#show_room,
#show_room .centered-wrapper{height:768px;}
#show_room{ background-color:<?php echo $res['fundo_show_room_cor']; ?>;}


/* #single-gallery{margin:42px 0 0 -2px;} */
#photos-container,
#photos-container .slides_container,
#photos-container .photos-slide{width:932px;height:466px;float:left;}
#photos-container .photos-slide a,
#photos-container .photos-slide a img,
#photos-container .photos-slide .filler{width:232px;height:232px;float:left;}
#photos-container .photos-slide a,
#photos-container .photos-slide .filler{margin:1px 1px 0 0;}
#photos-container{position:relative;}
#photos-container .prev{
    width:232px;
    height:232px;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border:none;
    background:url(../img/btn_prev2_bco.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    opacity:0.6;
        -moz-opacity:0.6;
        -webkit-opacity:0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:0;
    text-indent:-99999px;
    z-index:99;
}
#photos-container .next{
    width:232px;
    height:232px;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border:none;
    background:url(../img/btn_next2_bco.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    opacity:0.6;
        -moz-opacity:0.6;
        -webkit-opacity:0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:0;
    text-indent:-99999px;
    z-index:99;
}
#photos-container .prev{left:0;top:1px;}
#photos-container .next{right:0;bottom:0;background-position:0 0;}
#photos-container .prev:hover,
#photos-container .next:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
        -moz-opacity:1.0;
        -webkit-opacity:1.0;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

</style>

<div id="show_room" class="sections full-width-wrapper bg_2"><!-- 01-->
    <div class="centered-wrapper"><!-- 02-->
        <div class="section-header">
            <?php //include 'menu_pags.php';?>          
        </div>


       <div style="margin-top:130px; float:left;">
        <?php include'js/config_show_room.php'; ?>
       </div>

    <div id="single-gallery" class="full-width-wrapper"><!-- 03-->
        <div id="photos-container" class="full-width-container"><!-- 04-->
            <div class="slides_container" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block; margin:0 auto;"><!-- 05-->
                <div class="photos-slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 932px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
                    <span class="filler"></span>
                        <?php
                        $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
                        $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];                        
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY codigo ASC LIMIT 6");                            
                            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                        ?>

                        <a class="fancybox" href="img_prod/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="">
                            <img width="232" height="232" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                </div>
                <div class="photos-slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 932px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
                    <span class="filler"></span>
                </div>

            </div><!-- 05-->
        </div><!-- 04-->
    </div><!-- 03-->
    </div><!-- 02-->
</div><!-- 01-->
<a href="#" class="prev"></a>
<a href="#" class="next"></a>
```

Coloco-me a disposição para mais informações se necessário.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma ajuda a solucionar esse problema, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Murilo, você está limitando as imagens buscadas do banco a um total de 6. Você tem duas opções: 1) Buscar todas as imagens e armazená-las em um array, percorrendo de 6 em 6. OU 2) Implementar uma requisição assíncrona que busque as imagens restantes no seu banco de dados, no caso da página 2 com OFFSET 7 LIMIT 12 (As próximas 6 imagens, no caso).

Comment: Bruno eu tentei não limitar a quantidade de imagens, porem ocorreu isso...Entre nesse endereço para verificar o que ocorre - (http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/) - mesmo assim não me traz todas as imagens, fica faltando a ultima imagem, a de numero 8. Tem como voce me mostrar como deveria ser feito, pois não tenho ideia de como implementar essa requisição que esta mencionando.

Comment: publiquei uma resposta para sua pergunta, explicando como fazer a implementação onde busca todos os resultados no select e apresenta de 6 em 6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Murilo,

A implementação mais rápida para o que você quer fazer seria carregar todas as imagens do banco em um array, como você pode notar você possui duas divs com a classe "photos-slide" dentro da div "slides_container".

Sendo assim você deveria listar do primeiro ao sexto elemento do array conforme você já está fazendo na primeira div com classe "photos-slide" e os próximos 6 na próxima div com mesma classe.

Para que isso seja feito dinamicamente proponho o seguinte código exemplar:

```
<div class="slides_container" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block; margin:0 auto;"><!-- 05-->

    <?php
            $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
            $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];                        

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY codigo ASC LIMIT 6");
            $contador_imagens = 0;

            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                //Nos índice de imagem divisíveis por 6, tais como 0, 6, 12, 18:
                if($contador_imagens % 6 == 0):
                ?>
                    <div class="photos-slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 932px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
                        <span class="filler"></span>
                <?php
                endif;

                //As linhas abaixo <a> até </a> serão executadas em todos os loops.
                ?>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="img_prod/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="">
                            <img width="232" height="232" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="" />
                        </a>
                <?php

                //Incrementa o contador de imagens antes do fim do while para que as tags não sejam fechadas imediatamente após abertas
                $contador_imagens++;

                //Fecha as tags abertas nos índices divisíveis por 6 após passadas 6 iterações da abertura da tag:
                if($contador_imagens % 6 == 0):
                ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endif;
            }
    ?>
</div><!-- 05-->
```

Comment: Olá Bruno, valeu pela dica, que funcionou quase que em 100%, esta faltando somente parar ao chegar na ultima imagem. Eu inseri 30 imagens, mas quando chega na 30ª, ele volta para a 1ª, mas volta com uma imagem por cima do botão NEXT. Ver no endereço (http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/). Sem querer ser abusado, mas já sendo...Rsrsrsrs... Tem como você me dizer como solucionar esse problema. Mas desde já, muito obrigado pela a ajuda.

Comment: Murilo, aparentemente o código que eu postei acima está sendo executado corretamente, porém logo abaixo algo está iterando os 30 resultados da tua consulta novamente de 12 em 12 imagens, por isso sobrepõe o botão NEXT. Caso não encontre o problema por favor abre uma nova questão com o código completo atualizado.

Comment: Isso mesmo Bruno, acabei de descobrir e alterar, agora esta funcionando beleza, valeu mesmo pela a sua ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Estou postando o código abaixo, funcionando do jeito desejado.

Agradeço ao amigo @Bruno Bermann que com sua dica ajudou para que o resultado fosse o positivo.

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

$fundo_show_room_img = $_POST['fundo_show_room_img'];
$fundo_show_room_cor = $_POST['fundo_show_room_cor'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM showroom");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>

<style>
/* SHOW-ROOM */
#show_room,
#show_room .centered-wrapper{height:768px;}
#show_room{background:url(../upload/<?php echo $res['fundo_show_room_img']; ?>) no-repeat center top #201537;}
#show_room{ background-color:<?php echo $res['fundo_show_room_cor']; ?>;}


/* #single-gallery{margin:42px 0 0 -2px;} */
#photos-container,
#photos-container .slides_container,
#photos-container .photos-slide{width:932px;height:466px;float:left;}
#photos-container .photos-slide a,
#photos-container .photos-slide a img,
#photos-container .photos-slide .filler{width:232px;height:232px;float:left;}
#photos-container .photos-slide a,
#photos-container .photos-slide .filler{margin:1px 1px 0 0;}
#photos-container{position:relative;}
#photos-container .prev{
    width:232px;
    height:232px;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border:none;
    background:url(../img/btn_prev2_bco.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    opacity:0.6;
        -moz-opacity:0.6;
        -webkit-opacity:0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:0;
    text-indent:-99999px;
    z-index:99;
}
#photos-container .next{
    width:232px;
    height:232px;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border:none;
    background:url(../img/btn_next2_bco.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    opacity:0.6;
        -moz-opacity:0.6;
        -webkit-opacity:0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:0;
    text-indent:-99999px;
    z-index:99;
}
#photos-container .prev{left:0;top:1px;}
#photos-container .next{right:0;bottom:0;background-position:0 0;}
#photos-container .prev:hover,
#photos-container .next:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
        -moz-opacity:1.0;
        -webkit-opacity:1.0;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

</style>

    <div id="show_room" class="sections full-width-wrapper bg_2">
        <div class="centered-wrapper">
        <div class="section-header">
            <?php //include 'menu_pags.php';?>          
        </div>


       <div style="margin-top:130px; float:left;">
        <?php include'js/config_show_room.php'; ?>
       </div>

    <div id="single-gallery" class="full-width-wrapper">
        <div id="photos-container" class="full-width-container">
            <div class="slides_container" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block; margin:0 auto;"><!-- 05-->

            <?php
            $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
            $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];                        
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img_show_room ORDER BY codigo ASC");
            $contador_imagens = 0;
            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            //Nos índice de imagem divisíveis por 6, tais como 0, 6, 12, 18:
            if($contador_imagens % 6 == 0):
            ?>
                    <div class="photos-slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 932px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
                        <span class="filler"></span>
            <?php
            endif;
            //As linhas abaixo <a> até </a> serão executadas em todos os loops.
            ?>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="img_show_room/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="">
                            <img width="232" height="232" src="img_show_room/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="" />
                        </a>
            <?php
            //Incrementa o contador de imagens antes do fim do while para que as tags não sejam fechadas imediatamente após abertas
            $contador_imagens++;
            //Fecha as tags abertas nos índices divisíveis por 6 após passadas 6 iterações da abertura da tag:
            if($contador_imagens % 6 == 0):
            ?>
                    </div>
            <?php
            endif; }
            ?>
            <?php
            $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
            $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];                         
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img_show_room ORDER BY codigo ASC");
            $contador_imagens = 0;  
            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            //Nos índice de imagem divisíveis por 6, tais como 0, 6, 12, 18:
            if($contador_imagens % 6 == 0):
            ?>
                    <div class="photos-slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 932px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
                        <span class="filler"></span>
            <?php
            endif;
            //As linhas abaixo <a> até </a> serão executadas em todos os loops.
            ?>
                        <a class="fancybox" href="img_show_room/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="">
                            <img width="232" height="232" src="img_show_room/<?php echo $res['imagem']; ?>" alt="" />
                        </a>
                <?php

                //Incrementa o contador de imagens antes do fim do while para que as tags não sejam fechadas imediatamente após abertas
                $contador_imagens++;

                //Fecha as tags abertas nos índices divisíveis por 6 após passadas 6 iterações da abertura da tag:
                if($contador_imagens % 6 == 0):
                ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endif;}            
                ?>
    </div><!-- 05-->
</div>
<a href="#" class="prev"></a>
<a href="#" class="next"></a>
</div></div>
```

Espero que possa ajudar a outros usuários com o mesmo problema.